# Accessibility in Interface Builder in Xcode 4.3

Tags: interface-builder, xcode4.3

I was wondering if anyone knows where the accessibility view in Xcode 4.3 is?

[image]

This is what I see in my IB; no tab for accessibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

`UITableView` doesn't have an accessibility drop down because the items *inside* it (the cell, or actually the label and the buttons and whatever else you put into a custom table view cell) will be the accessibility items the user is looking for.

Original answer:

The accessibility label is available on many various `UIView` subclassed objects (such as controls like buttons).

If you're looking at the detail for any object in XCode 4's XIB / Interface Builder editor, you'll see a drop down field that looks like the below:

[image]

Comment: Just updated my question but basically i dont see that on mine. If you see my screenshot, i am selecting a sample view,such as a uitableview, but even with uibarbutton etc, i see the same thing.

Comment: I just updated my answer Doron.  The items *inside* a table view are the things that the user is looking for, in terms of accessibility.  If you **must** add accessibility to your table view, you can subclass `UITableView` to something new (e.g. `DoronTableView`) and give that subclass accessibility properties programatically.

Comment: Got it thanks. i think thats what i needed and its mentioned in the accessibility guidelines Apple provides. Just spotted it now. Thanks Michael